# How to scale Jenkins slaves according to Build Queue on Kubernetes Plugin

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-plugins

I'm running on the Jenkins pipeline, so I have set the value to `Time in minutes to retain agent when idle` in slave configuration after I have run my jobs my slave but when the other job needs to run if a slave agent is full, jobs are waiting on Build Queue.

How I can scale the my slave count on Jenkins with Kubernetes plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `Container Cap` setting, if you're using the Jenkins Configuration as Code (JCasC) plugin this is configured via the `containerCapStr` key.